# Trying to make a loop that makes a new directory with modified files from an old directory

Tags: python, python-3.9

I have a folder with .fasta files and one csv file with the list of modification that I need to make to my fasta folder.

A typical fasta file (second line is the actual data):

```
> TCTCG (this is called the header)
TAGACTGTGTCGATATGCAATAAACATATTAACTACAGGTATTCGGGTAT
```

The csv file has three columns. The first column is the name that corresponds to the name of the files in the old directory, and the third column has the new header that needs to become the new header, so `>TCTCG` is replaced by an item from the third column, while the second line of the fasta file remains the same.

I thought the best way to do this would be to extract  the first column of the csv file (the names of the old files), loop through the old folder using the names from the first column and copy all the second lines. Then copy all the new headers from the third column of the csv file and then make a new directory and just paste the third column items and the second line from the old files in each new file (with the old name).

I am able to extract the second line from all the old files and read through the third column of the csv file but when I try to make a new directory and "write"/"append" the new lines, nothing happens. I have minimal experience with file I/O so, right now can't tell what went wrong.

```
import glob, os
from typing import Counter

def main():
    header_changes_knife = open('header_changes.csv','r') # the name of the csv file where the first column is the list of names of files and the third columns is the headers
    for i in header_changes_knife:
        firstColumn = [line.split(',')[0] for line in header_changes_knife] # makes a list of the first column of the header changes file, the name of the fasta file
        header_changes_knife.seek(0)
        third_column_read = [line.split(',')[2] for line in header_changes_knife] #makes a list of the third column of the header changes file, the new headers
        my_pass_to_fasta_opener = my_fasta_opener(firstColumn) # passes the first column to the function that actually reads and opens the fasta files
        for my_new_dir in header_changes_knife:
            os.chdir('C:\\Users\\dhaka\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Semester material\\Data Skills class\\All Homework\\two\\10\\pauls_dna_seqs\\Updated directory')
            make_new_file = open(firstColumn,"w")
            make_new_file.writelines(firstColumn)
            make_new_file.writelines(third_column_read)

def my_fasta_opener(my_list):
    counter = 0
    for my_file in my_list:
        os.chdir('C:\\Users\\dhaka\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Semester material\\Data Skills class\\All Homework\\two\\10\\pauls_dna_seqs')
        file_open = open(my_list[counter])
        file_open.readline()
        second_line = file_open.readline()
        return second_line
        counter += 1

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to parse a CSV file without much effort. Here, I assume that you have at least two columns with a respective header in the CSV file.

The fasta file can be split into the two things we're interested in: `header` and `data`. For every file, we update the header according to our CSV. Then we store our updated data structure to disk.

```py
import csv

def read_csv(filename):
    """ Returns a list of rows, where each row is a dict """
    print(f'Reading csv file {filename}')
    with open(filename) as f:
        return list(csv.DictReader(f))

def read_fasta_file(filename):
    """ Returns a string tuple (header, rest_of_the_file) """
    print(f'Reading fasta file {filename}')
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.read()
    lines = content.spltlines()
    
    # header is the first line
    # data is the rest of the file
    header, data = lines[0], '\n'.join(lines[1:])
    return header, data


# Assumption: We have at least the columns
# target_file: The file you want to update
# new_header: The updated header
updates = read_csv('myfile.csv')

fasta_files = ['data1.fasta', 'data2.fasta']
# This is dict of the form
# {
#   'data1.fasta': ('TCTCG', '...'),
#   'data2.fasta': ('TCTCG', '...'),
# }
fasta_files = {filename: read_fasta_file(filename) for filename in fasta_files}

# Produce a new dict with the same format, but updated header values
updated_files = {}
for update in updates:
    target_filename = updates['target_file']
    old_header, data = fasta_files[target_filename]
    new_header = updates['new_header']
    updated_files[target_filename] = (new_header, data)

# Write the changes to disk
for filename, (header, data) in updated_files:
    print(f'Outputting to updated_{filename}')
    content = header + '\n' + data
    with open(f'updated_{filename}', 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)
```

Comment: Thanks man. I def don't understand all of it right now but I think I can parse through it. Also, had no idea that there is a dedicated csv module.

Comment: There are a ton of built-in modules for all kinds of stuff, definitely worth looking into. Also, if the post was helpful to you, I'd appreciate if you marked it as the correct answer :)

Comment: I marked it as the right answer. Once again, thank you